# import error does not occurs only when required library is installed while repl is running

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, pypy

I'm trying to test cppyy module in pypy.
cppyy requires reflex library, so I installed it.
without it, an error occurs

```
>>>> import cppyy                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: missing reflection library libcppyy_backend.so
```

While python repl is still runing, I install reflex library and after that, 'import cppyy' works.
However, when I close the repl and run it again and try to import cppyy, it does not works again(the error above). The point is that only when I install reflex library while repl is running, 'import cppyy' succeeds.
I think that the real problem is not about cppyy or reflex and there have been similiar problems with python repl. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused by this behavior of PyPy (which is a bug, should be reported to http://bugs.pypy.org/ ):

If you type `import cppyy` once, it fails with the ImportError shown above, but inconsistently, trying again immediately `import cppyy` "works".  Of course, you actually get a broken module.

To answer your real question, it seems that you failed to install libcppyy_backend.so.  Make sure it is at the right place, as documented.